# Tab instead of Enter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a **System.Windows.Controls.TextBox** and if the user presses the **enter**-key, i want the application to handle it like a **tab**-key, so that the user can jump to the next input control, like he would normally do with the tab key. Is this somehow possible?

P.S.: I couldn't find a answer without usings of "System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}");", which i would not like to include in my WPF-Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `TextBox1.AcceptsReturn = false;`
Add a KeyDown/KeyUp/KeyPress handler to the textbox and if the key is Enter or Return, invoke 
 `TextBox1.MoveFocus (new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next))`;

Comment: this one worked out best for me (I'm still learning WPF). thanks for your answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if is what you want, but in the code you can use the KeyDown event to have something like:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.TheKeyYouWant)
        {
          NextElementToBeFocus.Focus();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        //code for any other type of exception
    }

}
```

With that you can have the key you want to act like a Tab.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i was looking for a more common approach as i already used this kind of pattern in another project of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the textbox keydown event enter this code:

```
If (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        This.SelectNextControl(TextBox1, True, False, False, False);
    }
```

The name of the Textbox is TextBox1.

Comment: didn't work for me...